# UICollectionView reloadSections with animation

Tags: objective-c, animation, uicollectionview

I'd like to reload UICollectionView with some interesting animation. In UITableView there's a method called `reloadSections:withRowAnimation`.
But in UICollectionView there's just `reloadSections`.

How can I customize reloadSections animation? I definitely saw this in apps on the App Store.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UICollectionView animate data change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272315/uicollectionview-animate-data-change)

Answer (score 32):

Just do it like that:

```
[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    [self.collectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]];
} completion:nil];
```

Comment: Then you have to dive deeper and write your own ```UICollectionViewLayout```. You cannot compare it with UITableView, because UICollectionView is not only ment to display data in 1D (like UITableView) or 2D (like with UICollectionViewFlowLayout). You are not limited to anything and so there are no trivial animations other than fading built in. It is not possible for custom layouts to use different slide-from-top/bottom/middle animations, because the animations cannot be defined globally!!!

Answer (score 27):

Swift 3 version:

```
collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
    let indexSet = IndexSet(integer: 0)
    self.collectionView.reloadSections(indexSet)
}, completion: nil)
```

Comment: You got leak here. Use `[weak self]`

Comment: No leak and no need for [weak self]. [weak self] is only needed for long-lived closures that create circular dependencies. This closure does not even escape.

Comment: exactly, its non-escaping closure so no need for weak self

Answer (score 2):

This article here is worth a read:
http://victorlin.me/posts/2016/04/29/uicollectionview-invalid-number-of-items-crash-issue

*TLDR:*

> So it turned out performBatchUpdates calls collectionView(*:numberOfItemsInSection:) first before call the given closure to know the item numbers. Next, it calls the closure, and eventually, it calls collectionView(*:numberOfItemsInSection:) again to check the number. And here is where the assertion exception thrown.